# Can I have flash disabled by default in auto mode on Canon EOS 7D Mark II?

Tags: canon, flash, camera-settings, canon-7d

Sorry for the naive question. Just bought the 7D mark II and was wondering why if I disable the flash in auto mode, turn the camera off and then on, the flash is again enabled. Is it possible to have it disabled by default for the auto mode?

Comment: Wouldn't using the `P` mode solve this problem?

Comment: It would, I was wondering if I could use full auto with flash disabled. Maybe it's possible to create a C1 for what I need, I don't know

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what is the difference between full auto without flash and the P-mode?

Comment: I don't know :) I'm a beginner

Comment: You can change things like WB, EC, and many other options in "P" mode. "Auto" mode doesn't allow such user control over anywhere near as many parameters as "P" mode.

Comment: My question is why in the world pay extra for the 7DII if you're going to shoot in "Auto"? In full "Auto" the 70D will produce pretty much the exact same pictures.

Comment: @MichaelClark, the camera is not for me, I bought it for my wife, but became curious about this feature. Compared to 70D, I liked the "full magnesium alloy body". It may sound childish, but I like those things for some reason :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to disable flash by default when using `Auto` mode: just use the `P` mode instead.

The `P` mode calculates the ISO, aperture and shutter speed automatically as well, but leaves some options for you to tweak. You can for example disable/enable the flash yourself and also decide to set the ISO yourself.

Comment: Unless you've selected "Auto" ISO, "P" mode does not use Auto ISO by default. It uses whatever value you had selected the last time you were in "P" mode. If safety shift is enabled and both aperture and shutter speed have been moved to selected limits then ISO will shift in "P" mode.

Answer (score 1):

A top tip, always shoot in 'P' Mode for whatever it is you are taking.  Then switch to 'M' for your creativity.

If you can see the light in your 'P' Mode (Fire off a shot and check in the LCD) then the settings should be followed in your 'M' Mode.
As a photographer.... I then Bracket 1 up 1 down to get the optimum shot (as well as 1 Raw 1 JPEG)

YES - P does Disable the Flash, as does Manual.

This is the basics of getting your shot right, without the flash, and using best use of the available light.

(PS. I use the Canon 7D as my Prime Camera, some may laugh, however it is as useful as any other Pro Camera 5 years ago.  It is what you can make it do that counts.  No need for the 5D or the 1D Full Frame, unless the customer insists on this of course.  To date I have never come across this or have been requested to use a Full Frame Only - if they did, I would just ask them to look elsewhere)
Hope this helps.